# How to use Tailwind colors in custom background linear-gradient rule with tailwind-merge?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, clsx

I'd like to use custom background rule in my tailwind class, something like this:

`bg-[linear-gradient(110deg,theme(colors.blue.200),45%,theme(colors.white),55%,theme(colors.blue.200))]`

and this particular class (with colors from tailwind theme) works well when it's placed into standard `class`, but I want to use it with tailwind-merge (twMerge function). Any ideas?

It works with `clsx`, but I'd like to combine those two libs with utility like:

```js
export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}
```